# Android Json to Server sends not data

Tags: php, android, json

I got a problem. I read a lot here but unfortunately I can't get an answer for my problem.
I want to send a Json post to my Server. The Server should then save the string in my database.

This is my server code so far:

```
<?php
include('db_connect.php');
$db = new _DB_Connect();
$db->connect();

if(isset($_POST['regid'])){
    $data = json_decode($_POST['regid']);

    $save_entry = "insert into gcm_users (gcm_regid) values ('$data')";
    mysql_query($save_entry) or die (mysql_error());
}else{
    echo 'no data get';
}

?>
```

And this is my method on my android phone.

```
public String sendJson(View view){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        String url2 = "http://192.168.0.5/control_center/functions/incomming.php";
        TextView textView_result;
        textView_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_result);

        //strict mode for networking
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url2);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type" , "application/json");

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("regid", "blablabla");
            String json = jsonObject.toString();

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            if(inputStream != null) {
                System.out.println(convertInputStreamToString(inputStream));
            }
            else {
                result = "Did not work!";
            }

            textView_result.setText(httpResponse.toString());
            System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Now the

```
System.out.println(convertInputStreamToString(inputStream));
```

tells me that I got no data

```
echo 'no data get';
```

So I get a response form the server but I could find my error, why the post data could not be retrieved.
Would appreciate any help or hints. Thank you.

Comment: You should add some more echo statements to your script. Specially first echo $_POST['regid'] to see if it is correct. I wonder why yo send a json text. The script is not expecting json. Only one variable value.

Comment: I could not echo out the first regid, because it's never been received. Or what do you mean?

Comment: `if(! isset($_POST['regid'])) echo ("regid not set in POST array"); else echo("regid set in postarray: $_POST['regid']");`. For test: Remove your database and sql code. First try to get the script to receive all parameters/values.

Comment: lack of PHP/HTTP's basics ... if you are using `application/json` you should read body(`php://input`) of request, and then parse it on PHP side, not "form" (since content type is not `application/www-form-urlencoded`) ... asked many times here, **search first!**

Comment: It is not needed to do such low level coding with php://input to receive json.

Comment: so how to get body? `$_POST['regid']` is for `application/www-form-urlencoded` ... I never write a line of code in PHP but I'm sure that you are worng! `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);`

Comment: Hmm why the -1 vote?
I changed the lines to 
`httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type" , "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");`

But I can't still get the data to pass to my php script.

Comment: @Selvin. I searched a bit and saw many threads using your suggestion. I never saw such before. So ok that can work. CSDev I think you are mixing it all up now. If you only want to send one regid you do not need json at all. If you want to use json you can put all json text in one basic name value pair(form-encoded). Or just output the json text (json-encoded). Just take the time to read threads about json requests.

Comment: @greenapps excatly ... he should decide to use either `application/www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json` and be consequent on both(server and client) side

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Later I have to send a little bit more data, thats because I'm trying to do it with Json.

So my code above in android is "correct" and my php script is wrong?

Comment: Ok. Understood. Just start with a php script only containing the line `echo(file_get_contents("php://input"));`. Very informative. Check if this works if you really want  to use php://input as lately i saw a thread here complaining that it did not work at certain php version.

Comment: It is equal for me what method I use to get the data to my script. It would be nice further if someone could tell me, whether my android file is correct, or not? :)

Comment: If you change the php script to the one liner i suggested you will see yourself if your Android code is ok or not. So just test.

Comment: Ok, I got it now with: 
`List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);`

This should be fine for my purpose! Thank you for your hints guys. No one Vote up would be nice again :)

Answer (score -1):

```
try this...

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("regid", "blablabla");
String json = jsonObject.toString();

MultipartEntityBuilder multiPart = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

multiPart.addTextBody("regid",json);
or 
multiPart.addTextBody("regid","blablabla");

httpPost.setEntity(multiPart.build());
```

Comment: I don't know which android api version you are using. But its builtin org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder; or you can download jar file from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime43jar.htm